# Build Devtoolset 7 gcc with "--enable-vtable-verify"

Tags: c++, vtable, gcc7, devtoolset

I have devtoolset7 packages installed in my machine

```
devtoolset-7-binutils-devel-2.28-11.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-runtime-7.1-4.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-binutils-2.28-11.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-gdb-8.0.1-36.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-libasan-devel-7.3.1-5.13.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.3.1-5.13.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel-7.3.1-5.13.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-valgrind-3.13.0-11.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-gcc-7.3.1-5.13.el7.x86_64
```

I am trying to build a binary with `-fvtable-verify=std`

Unfortunately, the gcc provided with devtoolset 7 is not built with `--enable-vtable-verify`

How can I rebuild devtoolset 7 gcc with `--enable-vtable-verify` with similar configuration as used by devtoolset 7.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the devtoolset is to remain backwards compatible with the system compiler and its older `libstdc++.so.6` library. The `--enable-vtable-verify` option creates an incompatible C++ runtime with a different ABI, which cannot be used with any existing libraries that weren't compiled with VTV enabled.

There is no point creating a devtoolset compiler (intended to be compatible with the system compiler) that is explicitly incompatible with the system compiler.

If you want to use VTV then just [build your own GCC from source](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) and enable VTV, but be aware that code compiled by that GCC will not be compatible with code compiled with the system compiler *or* the devtoolset compiler.